# Loading large dataset to a gridview - UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, windows-10

I have 10000 objects (that require a lot of processing) to load to a GridView on my UWP app.
(Look at the image with the red highlighted area.)
[image: Look at the image with red highlighted area]

First I need to get all the 10000 records from DB and then progressively process each object and then load it into the view while maintaining UI responsiveness.

One problem is currently as a requirement app need to display data horizontally with only 1 row, so I used a GridView. Here is the XAML.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <GridView x:Name="MeetingGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding MeetingList}" Tag="{Binding MeetingList}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}" SelectionChanged="MeetingGridViewSelectionChanged"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MeetingBoxDataTemplate}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

I have implemented ISupportIncrementalLoading but due to the way I designed the XAML, it does not function well with the scrolling. Instead of progressively load data, it loads everything to the view. So until everything processed and load to the view GridView is non responsive.

Here is the incremental loading code.

```
public class ItemsToShow : ObservableCollection<MeetingModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
    {
        public int lastItem = 0;

        public bool HasMoreItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (_globalDisplayMeetings == null || itemsToSkip == _globalDisplayMeetings.Count || itemsToSkip > _globalDisplayMeetings.Count)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        List<MeetingModel> items = new List<MeetingModel>();
        int itemsToSkip = 0;
        public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
        {
            if (itemsToSkip > _globalDisplayMeetings.Count()) { }

            ProgressBar progressBar = ((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MeetingsPage).PgbPage;
            CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

            return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
            {
                await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low,
                    () =>
                    {
                        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
                        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    });

                items = _globalDisplayMeetings.Skip(itemsToSkip).Take((int)count).ToList();
                itemsToSkip = itemsToSkip + (int)count;

                await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low,
                    () =>
                    {
                        foreach (MeetingModel item in items)
                        {
                            this.Add(item);
                        }

                        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                    });

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };
            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to fix this. The behavior I need is same as Android recyclerview. 
Anything will help. Thanks.

Comment: can you not chunk your data? do you need all objects all the time? use chunking and aggregations in the database backend and only return the results to your gui / the objects you actually work right now in the gui.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Data need to be present on the page for filtering purposes.

Comment: In that case you should be able to send that filter argument to the database and return the resultset. Even this might not be the answer you want, it is the only way which could help me process huuuge amounts of data in client applications. If this is really not possible, you should look for librarys which allow you to create indexes on your local data, this could greatly boost your performance, maybe a small local database? Maybe another guy will post a better approach, but I could not find one for my use cases.